# Java Swing how to create a text box that updates based on a user entry?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

I'm creating a Book Tracking application where the user enters in a book and once entered, the book name will show up on the screen.

I've been searching the web for what kind of component would be able to do this for me and I can't find anything. JTextArea doesn't work because the user can write into it directly which I dont want. I want the text box to change once the user has finished entering in a book....

Comment: *"JTextArea doesn't work because the user can write into it directly which I dont want."* `jTextarea.setEditable(false);` and a tip: always carefully read the API docs of the classes being used.

Comment: Maybe use a JList to hole the list of books?